# MS Teams - Can I make a custom tab only available to my organization

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to generate a bunch of custom tabs that are grouped together in several separate packages (manifest.json) files, but these custom tabs should only be available to people inside my organization.  From what I have read it doesn't appear that this is really possible.

It looks like the only 2 solutions that exist for this is to either side-load the files into each Team, which is not something that I want to have users doing.  Or publish it, so everybody in the world would see it, but then use authentication in the configuration tab to prevent anybody outside of my company from being able to save and add the tab.

I wanted to get confirmation that what I'm reading is correct and there is no way to limit who sees my different packages.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any way currently of administering tabs across multiple teams, short of adding or side-loading as you mention.  We should have a better story in the next few months.